# Changin .each jQuery into toArray()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to change `.each` solution into `toArray()` . The thing is that i need to make 2 similar functions that use the same `.each` solution, so to make it faster i want to make another one with `toArray()` and just implement it inside other two.

My function:

```
function inputValidator() {
                      $(' input').each(function() {
                       var element = $(this);
                       if (!element.val() == "") {
                            element.closest('.my_item').removeClass('error');
                           
                         }
                        if (!reg.test(element.val())) {
                             element.closest('.my_item').addClass('error');                                            
                        }   
                      });
```

Another function is very similar and have the same:

```
$(' input').each(function() {
  var element = $(this);
```

So, to make it faster i would like to put it into array, but have no idea how to implement it. I have tried solution with

```
var inputs = $( "input" ).toArray()
```

but all i get is error "inputs.toArray is not a function".

Here is code how i have implemented it with other function:

```
function common_inputs() {
                var inputs = $(' input').toArray();
                
                    var element = $(this);
                    if (!element.val() == "") {
                        element.closest('.my_item').removeClass('error');
                    }
                    if ( !reg.test(element.val())) {
                        element.closest('.my_item').addClass('error');                                            
                    }   
            
        }             
            
            function inputValidator2() {
                    common_inputs()
                    var element = $(this);
                    if (element.val() == "") {
                        element.closest('.my_item').addClass('error');
                    }                                               
            }
```

Anyone has idea how to implement it?

Comment: did you include [jQuery](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp)?

Comment: `inputs` is already an array in the code shown. Are you using `toArray()` more than once?

Comment: if you are interested in plain js you can write: document.querySelectorAll('input').forEach(function(ele) {.....

Comment: @gaetanoM yes i did and im afraid i need to have it with jQuery

Comment: @charlietfl no only once - you can check it because i have edited my post

Comment: `toArray()` works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/c5wby9nm/1